# Do I have to use both of these methods?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When I expand a UITableViewCell on touch, I know I have to update the UITableView. Right now I'm doing:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Do I need to use both updates methods as well as the reload method? Or is it just one or the other? I'm not completely understanding, so a little explanation would be fantastic. Thanks!

Comment: it's not "one or the other". They are used for different purposes. `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` are used for grouping insertions, deletions, etc. together so that they are animated simultaneously. They don't actually modify anything. But if you had read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/beginUpdates), this would have been clear.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I had previously read something in the documentation about reloadRowsAtIndexPaths being called in an animation block defined by the beingUpdates and endUpdates methods. And looking at similar threads on stackoverflow, both of these solutions have been recommended for what i'm trying to accomplish. That's why I was slightly confused. Sorry if the question seems lazy, but I was genuinely looking for a little explanation after reading the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't have to use both. Either you go with `reloadCell` technique or cell updates via `beginUpdate` and `endUpdate`.

When you are reloading a particular row, internally table view system creates 2 cell and then blends in the new one with. You can remove the `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` and simply call this to change the height. But animation won't be smooth and you will observe the line for small cell while animation back from the larger cell height.

As for `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` they are used for group insertion, deletion etc. but it is an old hack to forcefully call the table view delegates and get the changed height for selected index. This technique handles the height change animation quite well. So your code will be like

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Write the code to track the selected index path.
    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
}
```

OR

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath          
 {
     [tableView beginUpdates]; // tell the table you're about to start making changes
     //Write the code to track the selected index path.
    [tableView endUpdates]; // tell the table you're done making your changes
 }
```